# Aspose cells java, How to create image from table/ListObject

Tags: java, aspose-cells

How to convert table/ListObject to and image?

In excel file I have tables, charts and images and I am using aspose cells java. My requirement is to get all these details as an independent images and there are api's to convert charts and shapes to convert into an image but there is no api for tables/ListObject. So can anybody knows how tables are converted into images using aspose calls java liberary

Comment: Please Make it clear and explain in good manner to make others to understand your question.

Comment: I think that you can use OpenOffice API to do this (http://www.openoffice.org/api/).

Comment: I have to use only aspose for that.

Comment: @downvoter please comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Convert table/ListObject to image

1. Get ListObject

   ListObject listObject = worksheet.getListObjects().get(0);
2. Now create a new workbook with having only this listObject.

```
public static Workbook createWorkBook(final Worksheet worksheet, final ListObject listObject) throws Exception {
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    Cells cells = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells();

    Cells cellsTobeCopied = worksheet.getCells();

    int totalNoOfRows = listObject.getEndRow() - listObject.getStartRow() + 1;
    int totalNoOfColumns = listObject.getEndColumn() - listObject.getStartColumn() + 1;

    cells.setStandardHeight(cellsTobeCopied.getStandardHeight());
    cells.setStandardWidth(cellsTobeCopied.getStandardWidth());

    // Set height of each row as the height of actual rows of table
    for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        cells.setRowHeight(row, cellsTobeCopied.getRowHeight(row));
    }

    // Set width of each column as the width of actual columns of table
    for (int column = 0; column < totalNoOfColumns; column++) {
        cells.setColumnWidth(column, cellsTobeCopied.getColumnWidth(column));
    }

    // Copy data of table from worksheet to newly created workbook cells
    for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < totalNoOfColumns; column++) {
            Cell copiedFrom = worksheet.getCells().get(listObject.getStartRow() + row, listObject.getStartColumn() + column);
            Cell copyTo = cells.get(row, column);

            copyTo.setHtmlString(copiedFrom.getHtmlString());
        }
    }

    // Create table in newly created workbook
    ListObjectCollection tables = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getListObjects();
    tables.add(0, 0, totalNoOfRows - 1, totalNoOfColumns - 1, listObject.getShowHeaderRow());

    return workbook;
}
```

1. Then convert this workbook as image with image option as property **'setOnlyArea'** as true

```
public static void toImage(final Workbook workbook, final String outputFilePath) throws Exception {
    ImageOrPrintOptions imgOptions = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
    imgOptions.setImageFormat(ImageFormat.getPng());
    imgOptions.setOnlyArea(true);

    Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
    SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(sheet, imgOptions);

    for (int j = 0; j < sr.getPageCount(); j++) {
        sr.toImage(j, outputFilePath);
    }
}
```

Workbook is the newly created workbook only having tha listObject and output file path is the absolute path where to save the output image.

Link: http://iandjava.blogspot.com/2013/07/convert-excel-document-to-images.html
with this link you can convert excel and its components to images.